# Cannot run WebGL content on WebView

Tags: webview, webkit, webgl, wxpython

I am trying to open a webpage with WebGL content from wxPython WebView. The engine used by WebView, `webkit`, has WebGL support.
How can I render the the WebGL content inside WebView?

The complete code used by me:

```
import wx
import wx.html2


class MyBrowser(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
        sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Maximize()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    dialog = MyBrowser(None, -1)
    dialog.browser.LoadURL("https://get.webgl.org/")
    dialog.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

gives the below screen 
[image]

Also, opening https://whatsmybrowser.org from the WebView identifies the browser as Safari (while using Ubuntu). See full description here: https://whatsmybrowser.org/b/X43YSDV.

Comment: the error seems to indicate that there is no support. So how do you know it is there?

Comment: @Igor The engine is webkit which officially support webGL: https://webkit.org/status/#?search=webgl. My assumption is that if the engine support it, then webkit should also, and I might be missing something somewhere.

Comment: not necessary. As a test can you open the site/page you are trying directly inside the browser (not with wxPython)? Will you get the same behaviour? You should read on how to tweak the browser to support what you need.

Comment: @Igor the page works fine in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find support for webGL inside wxpython webview.
My solution was to use [cefpython](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython). cefpython embeds full chromium browser inside python applications. Here's an example of wxpython using cefpython: https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/wxpython.py.